# I cannot get data from my database with cookie token

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want search history data from my db with saved cookie token but i cannot get, history array always get empty how fix this situation.

```
public function get()
    {
        $cookieToken = Cookie::get('search_token');
        $userId = Auth::id();

        $history = $this->getSearchHistory($cookieToken, $userId);
        $popular = $this->getPopularSearches();

        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'success',
            'message' => 'Search History',
            'data' => [
                'history' => $this->transformSearchHistory($history),
                'popular' => $this->transformPopularSearches($popular)
            ]
        ]);
    }
```

```
protected function getSearchHistory($cookieToken, $userId)
    {
        return SearchHistory::select('search_term', DB::raw('MAX(id) as id'), DB::raw('MAX(cookie_token) as cookie_token'), DB::raw('MAX(user_id) as user_id'))
            ->where(function ($query) use ($cookieToken, $userId) {
                if (!empty($userId)) {
                    $query->where('user_id', $userId);
                } elseif (!empty($cookieToken)) {
                    $query->where('cookie_token', $cookieToken);
                }
            })
            ->groupBy('search_term')
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->limit(6)
            ->get();
    }
```

```
 protected function transformSearchHistory($history)
    {
        return $history->map(function ($item) {
            return [
                'id' => $item->id,
                'search_term' => $item->search_term,
                'cookie_token' => $item->cookie_token,
            ];
        })->toArray();
    }
```

1. {status: "success", message: "Search History",…}

   1. data: {history: [{id: 4, search_term: "Apple", cookie_token: "RHyIYWSXsgBtKPj7RuPG0jNM5m9mnRZO"},…],…}

      1. history: [{id: 4, search_term: "Apple", cookie_token: "RHyIYWSXsgBtKPj7RuPG0jNM5m9mnRZO"},…]

         1. 0: {id: 4, search_term: "Apple", cookie_token: "RHyIYWSXsgBtKPj7RuPG0jNM5m9mnRZO"}
         2. 1: {id: 2, search_term: "Samsung", cookie_token: "ZFqKwNJA6AKLaorkcODALjgJBPPcywU7"}
         3. 2: {id: 1, search_term: "Beko", cookie_token: "ZFqKwNJA6AKLaorkcODALjgJBPPcywU7"}
      2. popular: [{id: 1, search_term: "Apple", count: 24}, {id: 2, search_term: "Samsung", count: 12},…]

         1. 0: {id: 1, search_term: "Apple", count: 24}
         2. 1: {id: 2, search_term: "Samsung", count: 12}
         3. 2: {id: 6, search_term: "Beko", count: 5}
         4. 4: {id: 7, search_term: "iphone", count: 3}
   2. message: "Search History"
   3. status: "success"

this i want result

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see an issue with the code. You need to debug at each line i guess to check where till your code is working. Laravel has `dd()` which help to dump and die to check the data of the varaibale.

Try:

> Check if search_token is available or empty

That could be the major reason of your empty data issue.

> Check the sql query.

Try using `toSql()` to check what the sql query was generated by code and manually run the query to understand where it is wrong.